# MongoDB Realm using GraphiQL: null value on nested object properties (when linked only)

Tags: mongodb, graphql

i am using GraphiQL from MongoDB Realm Interface.

I got 2 entity in my model 'Training' and 'Buildind'.

When i request Buildings list all is ok.
[image]

When i request Trainings list with linked building, i dont have value on **vacations** **start_date** and **end_date**

[image]

is it a bug or did i missed something on my rules ?

TRAINING SCHEMA  :

```
 "title": "training",
 "properties": {
   "_id": {
     "bsonType": "objectId"
   },
   "building": {
     "bsonType": "objectId"
   } (...)
 }
}
```

TRAINING RELATION

```
{
  "building": {
    "ref": "#/relationship/stitch-club-service/club-db/building",
    "foreign_key": "_id",
    "is_list": false
  }
(...)
}
```

BUILDING SCHEMA

```
{
  "title": "building",
  "properties": {
    "_id": {
      "bsonType": "objectId"
    },
    "vacations": {
      "bsonType": "array",
      "items": {
        "bsonType": "object",
        "properties": {
          "start_date": {
            "bsonType": "date"
          },
          "end_date": {
            "bsonType": "date"
          }
        }
      }
    },
  (..)
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you get an answer yet?